# mod_wsgi: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "xxx"

Tags: django, docker, apache, mod-wsgi

There's about a hundred posts on this subject and none of them seem to have much rhyme or reason.

My configuration:

1. Trying to build a container via Podman with Apache + mod_wsgi (4.6.4) + Django, there is no virtualenv.
2. Install of compiled libs via CentOS package repo binaries. Python 3.6 via CentOS repo binary.
3. Install of pure python libs via pip, to --user (/home/user/.local)
4. Project folders are in /home/apache, no need for anything static I'll push all of that to a CDN.
5. The test file example from [the docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html#wsgi-application-script-file) works fine.
6. Migrations and post-migration signals work fine.
7. The dev server works fine with the current config.
8. The only environment variable I have specified Django and base-Python related is DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE which is set correctly to my base settings file.
9. Apache config, straight from the Django 3.2 docs:

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/apache
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     ServerName localhost
     WSGIScriptAlias / /home/apache/base/wsgi.py
     <Directory /home/apache/base>
      <Files wsgi.py>
         Require all granted
      </Files>
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the result:

```
[ 09:20:57.757787 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]   Traceback (most recent call last):
[ 09:20:57.758173 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "/home/apache/base/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[ 09:20:57.758542 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]       application = get_wsgi_application()
[ 09:20:57.758740 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "/home/apache/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[ 09:20:57.759100 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]       django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[ 09:20:57.759335 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "/home/apache/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[ 09:20:57.759539 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]       configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[ 09:20:57.759844 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "/home/apache/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
[ 09:20:57.760108 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]       self._setup(name)
[ 09:20:57.760483 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "/home/apache/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
[ 09:20:57.760772 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[ 09:20:57.761133 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "/home/apache/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
[ 09:20:57.762015 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[ 09:20:57.762347 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[ 09:20:57.762636 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[ 09:20:57.763139 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[ 09:20:57.763347 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[ 09:20:57.763613 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[ 09:20:57.763895 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[ 09:20:57.764154 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[ 09:20:57.764414 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[ 09:20:57.764702 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[ 09:20:57.764985 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[ 09:20:57.765289 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[ 09:20:57.765555 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[ 09:20:57.765874 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[ 09:20:57.766160 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 5:tid 140007184484096]   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "'base"
10.0.2.100 - - [02/Aug/2021:09:20:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"
```

Is it that extra single quote next to "base"?  I figure it must be, and there's no obvious indication where it came from.

It's not in any Apache config I can see. Nor is it in my site code, did a global Sublime search for 'base and everything looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Having identical settings in environment variables and wsgi.py denoted by different string quoting style was causing this.

wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "base.settings.dev")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Due to the settings not getting picked up properly in a previous step of the Docker compose routine, I specified in an env file that was passed to the container the following...

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='base.settings.dev'
```

Omitting one or the other caused the server to work.

Guess this doesn't apply anymore with Docker and Podman...

[image]